# Passing userdata file to AWS Cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a shell script(userdata file) and wondering is there a CLI command parameter that allows user to launch Cloudformation stack with userdata file?

Comment: what is the difference between your so called "userdata file" and the template itself?

Comment: Can you explain your use case some more?

Comment: Userdata scripts for say cloudinit can be fairly long shell scripts. Editing them inline in the template can be a royal pain. It is nice to have them in their own file and inject it into the template when creating it.

Answer (score 22):

Inside your template, use a CloudFormation parameter for the instance userdata:

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    "UserData": {
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "Instance": {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties" : {
        "UserData" : { "Ref" : "UserData" },
        ...
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Assuming you're using a Unix-like command line environment, create your stack like this:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name myStack \
    --template-body file://myStack.json \
    --parameters ParameterKey=UserData,ParameterValue=$(base64 -w0 userdata.sh)
```

Comment: Hi Ataylor, this is exactly what I was looking for. What is the command for Windows?

Comment: You can use the same command in Windows with cygwin or git bash.  If you use cmd.exe, you'll need to find a utility program to base64 encode the script, I think.  PowerShell should be able to do this as well, but I'm not certain about the details.

Comment: How could I add the --template-body in case we create the stack from the AWS console instead of from a command?

Comment: @ataylor, what if I have variables in userdata.sh, defined in the "Parameters" section of the template, that I want to be substituted by CloudFormation? For instance, I have a following variable in the script: ${AWS::StackName}

Answer (score 1):

Your user-data must exist in the CloudFormation template when you create the stack. You can write a script to read in your user-data from the file and insert it into the CloudFormation stack prior to creating the stack. Note that you may need to make formatting changes to the userdata (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-userdata).

Comment: Can you please provide an example? Just want to find out the syntax.