# Cloudformation ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cloudformation, user-data, launch-configuration

I am attempting to write a Cloud Formation Template that will create a launch configuration, ASG, ECS cluster, and register the ec2 instances in the ASG to said cluster.

I have a long userdata.sh file that is used to setup a launch configuration.

By putting this userdata in the yaml file
 i.e.

```
   ...
   UserData:
      Fn::Base64: !Sub | 
        #!/bin/bash
        ...
```

it looks pretty terrible. Also, when i try and plug in the cluster name into the ecs agent ${ECSCluster} with Sub, i get "variable names in Fn::Sub syntax must contain only alphanumeric characters, underscores, periods, and colons". The environment variables in my userdata take on the same form ${ENV_VARIABLE}.

I've tried [Passing userdata file to AWS Cloudformation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195137/passing-userdata-file-to-aws-cloudformation-stack) but receive "Template format error: YAML not well-formed. "

What is the recommended way for passing in a complex userdata.sh file into a CFT in such a way that you can add the cluster name to the ecs-agent config?

Answer (score 1):

Error is just stating that it doesn't like the way you reference your variable in `Fn::Sub`. Instead of `$(ECSCluster)` it needs to be `${ECSCluster}`. See the [examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#w2ab2c21c28c56c11) in the docs.

Comment: I actually do use ${ECSCluster}, that was a typo sorry

Comment: There is almost definitely a problem with variable references in your user data (or in any other part of your CF template that uses `Fn::Sub`). Maybe, CF template compiler considers something to be a variable reference, which is not intended to be so. It's hard to tell without seeing how it looks like.

Comment: if I'm referencing environment variables in the format ${ENV_VAR} how can CFT differentiate between environment variables and resources?

Comment: I believe it can't. Can you try to reference environment variables as `$ENV_VAR` and leave CF template variables formatted as `${CFT_VAR}`?

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone else having similar issues.  This error can happen even if you misplaced any ending brackets of variables, for example

```
 - !Sub 'https://sqs.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${AWS::AccountId/${SQSName}'
```

In the above code } is missing in the AccountId.